# Can someone clarify covariant return types in Java(6)?

Tags: java, generics, overriding, covariance

I *think* I'm asking about covariant return types.  I have some generated code that I'm trying to extend and use.  Let's suppose I have the following two classes:

```
public class SuperParent
{
    public List<SuperChild> getList()
    {
        return new ArrayList<SuperChild>();
    }
}
public class SuperChild
{
}
```

Now, I want to derive new classes from these thusly:

```
public class SubParent extends SuperParent
{
    public List<SubChild> getList()
    {
        return new ArrayList<SubChild>();
    }
}
public class SubChild extends SuperChild
{
}
```

The problem is, apparently I can't override the getList() method because the return type doesn't match, despite both classes being extended in the same direction.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding of `co-variant` is correct but usasge is not. `List<SubChild>` is not the same as `List<SuperChild>`

Consider this, `List<Animals>` is not the same as `List<Dogs>` and things can go horribly wrong if that was allowed. A `Dog` is an `Animal` but if it was allowed to assign like below:

```
List<Dogs> dogs = new ArrayList<Dogs>();
List<Animals> animals = dogs; //not allowed.
```

then what happens when you add a cat to it?

```
animals.add(new Cat());
```

and

```
Dog dog = dogs.get(0); //fail
```

So its not allowed.

As sugested by many others, use `List<? extends SuperChild>`  as return type to solve your problem.

**EDIT**
To your comment above, if you do not have control over super class, i am afraid, you can not do anything.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks, this is a lot clearer.  It's too bad; I wonder if I can still use List<Animals>, and cast the variables in the types where necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that with generics `List<SuperChild>` and `List<SubChild>` are not compatible, since if you'd call `getList()` on a `SubParent` instance but through a `SuperParent` interface, you'd get a return value of type `List<SuperChild>`. This would allow you to add other instances of `SuperChild` *even though* the list is only allowed to contain instances of `SubChild` (as per the return type defined in `SubParent`).

To make this compile change the return type to `List<? extends SuperChild>`, i.e.

```
public class SuperParent
{
  public List<? extends SuperChild> getList()
  {
    return new ArrayList<SuperChild>();
  }
}
```

This would allow you to return lists of subtypes but would not allow you to add elements to the list returned using the super type (i.e. you can't add elements to a `List<? extends SuperChild>`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  Now, my complication is that SuperParent is generated code - I can't alter it.

Comment: @end-user If you can't influence how `SuperParent` is generated you'd have to return `List<SuperChild>` from `SubParent#getList()` as well (if you can influence that code at least). If you could influence the code generation to some extent it might also be viable to not use generics here, although that might produce problems in other locations.

Answer (score 2):

`List<SubChild>` is **not** an subclass of `List<SuperChild>`

There is no co-variance in java's generics.

So, when you try to co-variant the return type, it is actually a different type, and java does not allow you to change it completely [since it will not be safe].

Your method `getList()` in `SubParent` should return `List<SuperChild>` [or `ArrayList<SuperChild>`, ...] to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out `List<SubChild>` is not a subclass of `List<SuperChild>`.

Depending on what you want to do, you could use generics:

```
public class SuperParent<T extends SuperChild>
{
    public List<T> getList()
    {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
public class SuperChild
{
}

public class SubParent extends SuperParent<SubChild>
{
    public List<SubChild> getList()
    {
        return new ArrayList<SubChild>();
    }
}
public class SubChild extends SuperChild
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine something like this:

```
SubParent subParent = new SubParent();
SuperParent superParent = (SuperParent) subParent; // upcast is okay
List<SuperChild> list = superParent.getList();
list.add(new SuperChild());
```

The last statement would violate the contract of SubParent.

A fix would be to change the contract of SuperParent's getList to `List<? extends SuperChild> getList()`.